# how to enum in a if with mybatis annotation

Tags: mybatis

I have a problem to write the syntax using an enum in a if in **MyBatis annotation**.

```
@Delete("<script>DELETE FROM tb_a WHERE "
        + "<if test='context.name().equals(ALBUM)'>"
        + " album_id = #{id}"
        + "</if>"
        + "<if test='context.name().equals(VIDEOLIBRARY)'>"
        + " videolibrary_id = #{id}"
        + "</if>"
      + "</script>")
 boolean delete(@Param("id") int id, @Param("context") EContext context);
```

**Enum**

```
public enum EContext {
    ALBUM,
    VIDEOLIBRARY,
    IMAGE,
    VIDEO,
}
```

the correct syntax as fare I know is like this `<if test="context.name().equals('ALBUM')">`
But I don't know how to write it with annotation.
I get this error message
[image]

Thanks for your help

***Edited to show more about the code***

Comment: Try `"<if test=\"context.name().equals('ALBUM')\">"`

Comment: Now I get this:     "nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'context.name().equals('ALBUM')'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "name" failed for object ALBUM [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.String.name()]"

Comment: I assumed that `context` is an enum, but it seems to be a string. Then there is no enum involved and you just need to compare two strings e.g. `context == 'ALBUM'`. If this is not the case, you need to provide the details (method signature, parameter class definition, etc.) so that others can understand the problem accurately or a repro like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).

Comment: I've edited the code to show more about the code

Comment: The problem still the same even for `context == 'ALBUM'` because it's not the correct writing. I've try with different charater ' or " or ` and no one works :( it doesn't see it's a string. I hope I explain me correctly

Comment: If I use an int instead of a string like this: `context == 1` it works, because I don't have to use character

Comment: This really isn't that complex... Here is an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-65386082).

Comment: Well @ave you're right, I don't know what to say. Maybe last night when I did you first answer I did a mistake on writing, It was 2am for me :D    Anyway a big thanks to you and thank you very much for you kind patience with me. Have a beautiful day

Comment: Please right the answer that I can acknowledge it :)

Comment: Haha, no worries. I'm happy to know it worked! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name()` method returns a `java.lang.String` and in OGNL, a string literal should be enclosed in single or double quotes.

So, the if element should be written as..

```java
+ "<if test=\"context.name().equals('ALBUM')\">"
```

or

```java
+ "<if test='context.name().equals(\"ALBUM\")'>"
```